# run python program (which is packaged and installed using pip) from command line as standalone client

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a .whl file from my python3 code and installed using pip. But I want to run it as standalone client from command prompt in Linux. what is the configuration I need to do?

For example in rasa we install using pip
pip install rasa

then we start like
rasa start

same thing I want to do for my python package

Comment: Just import the method from your package using `from rasa import Start` then `Start()`

Answer (score 0):

If you've built your package using `setuptools` and `setup.py` you can use `entry_points` to specify the entry point for your package. That way you can use your package as a console script.

Please look at: [Entry Points](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html)